# How to check if current page is HomePage in Ionic2?

Tags: ionic2

I can not figure out how. this.navCtrl.getActive() === HomePage return red in typescript. And this.navCtrl.isActive(HomePage) return error.

Comment: The whole point of typescript is to get you type definitions to things. So why don't you look at what the function takes and returns?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewController in Ionic 2 to check current page.

For example:

```
     import {ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
        @Component({
         templateUrl: 'build/pages/customer/customer.html'
        })
        export class CustomerPage {
        constructor(private _nav : NavController, private ViewController: ViewController) 
        {
        this.nav = _nav;
        this.ViewController = ViewController;

       //print current page
       console.log(this.ViewController.name);
        }
```

Cheer!